# Add lightning icon and lightning badge to lightning tabset using the Aura set attribute

Tags: community

Okay I am sorry I haven't been clear on what I am trying to achieve here.

I am trying to make a custom lightning tabset with each tab having a lightning icon and a badge. I know that somebody mentioned here the lightning:tabset component doesn't allow to have icons on its label attribute, so I had to go manually create a tabset:
Here is what I have so far:

```
    <div class="slds"> 
    <div class="slds-tabs-default">
        <ul class="slds-list_horizontal slds-tabs-default__nav" role="tablist">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.supOpps}" var="sup">
                <li id="{!sup.name}" class="slds slds-tabs-default__item slds-text-title--caps" onclick="{!c.onClickThis}" role="presentation">
                    <a role="tab">
                        <div>
                            <lightning:icon iconName="standard:people" size="x-small"/>
                            {!sup.name} 
                        </div>                                                               
                    </a>                        
                </li>
            </aura:iteration>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
    onClickThis :function(component, event, helper){        
    var sup = event.currentTarget.id;
    var tab1 = component.find(sup);
    $A.util.addClass(tab1, 'slds-active');
    //console.log(thistab);
    let oppsAll = component.get("v.oppsTemp");
    var oppsbySup;
    if(sup == "All"){
        oppsbySup = oppsAll;
    } else {
        oppsbySup = oppsAll.filter(x => { 
            return x.sumchans__Owner_Manager__c === sup;
        });  
    }    
    component.set("v.opps", oppsbySup);
},
```

The functionality that I am looking works good so far.

How would I go about making it look like a tab with applying active class to the tabs that is clicked and deactivate the previous selected tab item. Looked around a lot for samples, found a few, being a newbie I found a lot of resources confusing.I wished the lightning tabset worked with icons and badges.

Comment: What do you mean by "Not Working for me"? What are you seeing, or not seeing?

Comment: I see the tab titles with the count. But there is no icon or badge.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning:tab attribute label used to be of type component[]. But in new release they made it text only.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tab/specification

label attribute definition as in documentation :- `The text that appears in the tab. The attribute accepts sting values, but for compatibility with previous releases also accepts a component type. Only the text portion of the label value displays and any CSS classes that are applied are ignored.`

They might again accept component type in future but for now it is text only.

Only possible solution can be creating your own custom tab component.

One of possible solution of your active class problem can be

Create a attribute of name selectedTab

then depending on value of selected tab set class sods-active in your li

```
class="{! join(' ', 'slds slds-tabs-default__item slds-text-title--caps', (v.selectedTab == sup.name ? 'slds-active', ''))}"
```

then in your js code

```
onClickThis :function(component, event, helper){        
    var sup = event.currentTarget.id;
    component.set('v.selectedTab', sup);
    let oppsAll = component.get("v.oppsTemp");
    var oppsbySup;
    if(sup == "All"){
        oppsbySup = oppsAll;
    } else {
        oppsbySup = oppsAll.filter(x => { 
            return x.sumchans__Owner_Manager__c === sup;
        });  
    }    
    component.set("v.opps", oppsbySup);
```

Comment: Okay. I am trying to make it using button group component which seems to be working with an icon and badge so far. Just checking how do I get the value of the iterated li item on to the controller? With the present setup it throws me an error when I click on the icon or the badge of the li item, how do I have the li item send a va loo use to the controller. Please advise.

Comment: @Sumchans there is a good salesforce documentation for that https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm. We can Set name of button in aura:iteration and then get event.getSource().get("v.name") to find out which button is pressed

Comment: I am sorry for making it super confusing for you all, I got the original post edited with detailed explanation on what I am trying to achieve. Please advise.

Comment: @Sumchans don't change all the details of any question. As now the description of question and question title are different. You can always ask new question and add other questions link for more details