# Trying to add lightning icon as part of the label attribute to lightning tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying very hard to get icons as part of the label attribute to lightning tab. This is my latest trial to make it work.
 Does this code work, or am i doing anything wrong?

```
     <aura:component implements="force:appHostable >   
           <aura:attribute name="tabLabel" type="Aura.Component[]"/>

<lightning:tabset onselect="{! c.tabSelect }" selectedTabId="{!v.selTabId}" variant="scoped">

     <aura:iteration items="{!v.supOpps}" var="sup">

            <aura:set attribute="tabLabel">
                <lightning:icon iconName="standard:user" size="small"/>
                <p>{!sup.name }</p>
                <span class="slds-badge"> {!sup.count}</span>
            </aura:set>  

            <lightning:tab class="slds-text-title_caps" label="{!v.tabLabel}" 
             id="{!sup.name}"> 
            </lightning:tab>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:tabset>   
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add lightning icon and lightning badge to lightning tabset using the Aura set attribute](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239364/add-lightning-icon-and-lightning-badge-to-lightning-tabset-using-the-aura-set-at)

Comment: ON that post which was mine, at the bottom it says to create a new question, so I created a new one stating exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only assign components to attributes that accept components (they will be documented as `Aura.Component[]`), and only if the rules allow it. Specifically, [lightning:tab label](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tab/specification) says:

> The text that appears in the tab. The attribute accepts sting values, but for compatibility with previous releases also accepts a component type. Only the text portion of the label value displays and any CSS classes that are applied are ignored.

In *general*, if you want to assign a value to an attribute, do so inside the component that's getting set, otherwise you'll get unpredictable results:

```
<lightning:tab class="slds-text-title_caps" id="{!sup.name}"> 
  <aura:set attribute="label">
    {!sup.name}
  </aura:set>
```

---

If you want to have non-standard features like icons on your tabs, you're going to have to build your own. The SLDS framework has a whole section on [tabs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tabs/).

Comment: Is there any way that we could make this work, like to have an icon as part of the label of the tab. It says for compatibility with previous releases it also accepts a component type. Or any other suggestions? Thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: @Sumchans just edited, but the short answer is, "build your own." The standard components only do exactly what is written in the documentation. If it's not in the documentation, it can't be done.

Comment: I did check that,  I got totally confused with it being a newbie.

Comment: @Sumchans You might take a look at [this tab](http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/tabset) from the Lightning Strike open source compnent set. Easier than starting from scratch.